# How proportionally to decrease the distance between two parts in one object without scaling those parts?

Tags: transforms, proportional-editing

I have a bench. I want to decrease the distance between two parts in the centre without scaling those parts and without standard moving with GX hotkeys. Yes, I can move each part of the bench with G, X but I want to know any other variants. When I tried to use SX those parts changed their scale.

[image]

Comment: If your object is symmetrical you can turn on x-mirror editing and only edit one side.

Comment: Or move on one side and symmetrize, other than that, I'm not sure there's another way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Mesh Symmetry
Assuming both sides of your mesh are identical, and it's origin is in the centre of the object, check this box for which axis you wish to model symmetrically around, in your case `X`
[image]

Then any edits done to one side will be also done to the other side
[image]

Comment: Dang it... Which I've just realized that's exactly what @Leander said 

Comment: But comments can disappear in future, so good job writing an answer.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusvonBroady 